# In Excel, how to find value against a date

Tags: arrays, excel

In Excel, say, I have a series of dates in column A, and some values in column B.

In a different cell I want to grab the value from column B for that row where column A has a specific date (I can specific the date in my formula).

What formula should I use?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for this:

```
=VLOOKUP(lookup_value,table_array,col_index_num,range_lookup)
```

`lookup_value` is the date you want to find, `table_array` should include columns A and B, `col_index_num` is the column you want to get (in this case, 2 for column B) and `range_lookup` is FALSE, since you seem to want an exact match:

Try this, for example (the date to look for should be put on C1, dates on A and values on B):

```
=VLOOKUP(C1, $A$1:$B$100, 2, FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks Emilio. I can't believe I didn't figure this one out considering I use vlookup quite a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Will all the dates be unique? If so, you could use SUMIF. Something like this:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A10,"the date I want",B1:B10)
```